# Flutter: disable ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an `ExpansionTile` that checks if the user is allowed to enable it:

```
ExpansionTile(
      tilePadding: widget.rent ? EdgeInsets.all(0) : null,
      onExpansionChanged: (bool value) {
        if (_canCreateBill) {
          setState(() {
            _billable = value;
          });
        } else {
          return Navigator.of(context)
              .pushNamed('/invoice-details')
              .then((val) async {
            await _getBillingInfo();
            setState(() {
              _billable =
                  _canCreateBill;
            });
          });
        }
        
        widget.onSwitchChange(value);
      },
      initiallyExpanded: _billable,
      title: Text(translate('expense.create_invoice')),
      subtitle: Text(translate('expense.create_invoice_info')),
      trailing: IgnorePointer(
        child: Switch(
          value: _billable,
          onChanged: (_) {},
        ),
      ),
      children: [
        Visibility(
          visible: _canCreateBill,
          child: _billingInfo(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

**Happy path:**
Here we have `_canCreateBill` which controls if the user can enable the switch. If the user clicks and he's not allowed, I moved him to a page to add some info. After adding that info, he comes back and the switch is enable.

**Problem:**
The user can go back without adding any info. The switch will be disable but the ExpansionTile will be active because we already clicked on it:

[image]

How can check for this also? Can we disable the `ExpansionTile` or force a click somehow?

This option is not a solution:

```
IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: true,
  child: ExpansionTile()
)
```